# Need a equation that defines a certain number

Tags: functional-equations

Im programming a function but I just cant structure the equation.
I think this is the right place to ask since the problem is completely mathematics.

Let me explain three scenarios.

There are 4 variables.

```
X, Y, Z and P. They all depend on each other.
X is the sum of Y * 1200.
So if Y is 3, X = 3600.
Z is known, decreasing by -1200. 0, -1200, -3600, -4800 etc..
P is unknown
```

Im trying to solve P, but first i need to structure the equation. Ill give it 3 scenarios with these variables:

```
X = 3600
Y = 3
```

- If `Z = 0` `P = 1`.
- If `Z = -1200` `P = 2`
- If `Z = -2400` `P = 3`

So I want a equation that sets P to a number as above.

God this is hard to explain. I hope someone gets it! Please comment if u have any questions.

**Im also new to this community so please let me know if Im doing something wrong in my question!**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $P(Z) = -\frac{Z}{1200} + 1$? How do $Z$ and $P$ depend on $X$ and $Y$, or are $X$ and $Y$ completely unrelated to them?

Comment: I guess they are! Ill try that function, thanks! Ill let you know if it worked. You are a genius! That worked! Thanks alot! Have a very nice day!